# SwiftUI TabView adding strange blank space underneath view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios17

I am using a tab view to change screens in my app. I am also using a custom tab bar that I created to navigate with.

The problem I have is the tab view seems like it's creating a random blank space underneath itself. I can't figure out if it's the custom tab view or not.

IMPORTANT: One thing to note is that if you click anywhere in the blank space it will actually navigate through the views - so it seems like it is actually an invisible tab bar?

Below is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var selectedTab = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            MyGarageView().tag(0)
            FuelView().tag(1)
            FinderView().tag(2)
        }
    }
    ZStack{
        HStack{
            ForEach((TabbedItems.allCases), id: \.self){ item in
                Button{
                    selectedTab = item.rawValue
                } label: {
                    CustomTabItem(imageName: item.iconName, title: item.title, isActive: (selectedTab == item.rawValue))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(6)
    }
    .frame(height: 75)
    .cornerRadius(15)
    .padding(.horizontal, 26)
  }    

}
```

CustomTabBarView:

```
enum TabbedItems: Int, CaseIterable{
    case myGarage = 0
    case fuel
    case map


var title: String{
    switch self {
    case .myGarage:
        return "Garage"
    case .fuel:
        return "Fuel"
    case .map:
        return "Finder"
    }
}

var iconName: String {
    switch self {
    case .myGarage:
        return "garage"
    case .fuel:
        return "fuel"
    case .map:
        return "map"
    }
  }
}

extension ContentView {
func CustomTabItem(imageName: String, title: String, isActive: Bool) -> some View {
    HStack(spacing: 10){
        Spacer()
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .foregroundColor(isActive ? .white : .gray)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        if isActive{
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(isActive ? .white : .black)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(width: isActive ? 150 : 60, height: 60)
    .background(isActive ? .black : .clear)
    .cornerRadius(15)
  }
}
```

I've tried hiding the tab view to no avail.

I've also tried playing around with the frames which had no effect.

I cannot see the issue and other posts / articles did not help either. I'm stuck :(

Comment: You've included screenshots from a private Google Drive folder. Please consider uploading the images directly to the question for easier access and viewing.

Comment: @Abdullah - my mistake, I've included a direct link to imgur now

Comment: The random blank space is the tab bar, but you just haven't added any items to it for each respective view. Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/tabitem(_:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to use a `TabView` is *either* to have a tab bar which is populated with `TabItem`, *or* to use page view style.

- When a tab bar is used, you attach a `TabItem` to each of the views in the `TabView`.
- When page view style is used, you can move between pages by swiping. This style of use does not have the blank space below it, but it does have a page indicator (dots) to show which page you are on.

You are not using either of these approaches. So there is no real need to be using a `TabView`.

However, if you really want to use a `TabView`, then one workaround for the blank space (when `.automatic` tab style is used) is to show the custom tab bar as an overlay. You might need to add more padding below the `TabView` to make more space for your custom tab bar, if the height of your tab bar is greater than the blank space you are trying to hide.

Like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        MyGarageView().tag(0)
        FuelView().tag(1)
        FinderView().tag(2)
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 30)
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        HStack{
            ForEach((TabbedItems.allCases), id: \.self){ item in
                Button{
                    selectedTab = item.rawValue
                } label: {
                    CustomTabItem(imageName: item.iconName, title: item.title, isActive: (selectedTab == item.rawValue))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(6)
        .frame(height: 75)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .padding(.horizontal, 26)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Although this works, you are relying on the blank space below the `TabView` being there, because if it wasn't there, your custom tab bar would overlap the page content. So you might want to reconsider, whether you really need to use a `TabView` at all.

An alternative approach would be to replace the `TabView` with a `ZStack` and then to switch between the different views according to the setting of the state variable `selectedTab`. The custom tab bar would work in exactly the same way. By avoiding `TabView` altogether, you would not be vulnerable to the layout of a `TabView` changing in a future iOS version.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I really appreciate it. I have used a ZStack and switched on selected tab to decide which view to display. It all works and loads perfectly.

Comment: Please to have been able to help Thanks for accepting the answer.