# Tabbar not hiding in iOS 17

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just upgraded my app from iOS 16 to 17, and the tab bar is no longer hidden.

I'm hiding the tab bar because I use a TabView with a custom tab bar.

The entry point of the app is structured as follows:

```
struct LandingView: View {

@State var selectedTab = 1

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                CreateView()
                    .tag(1)
                // ...
            }
        }
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        // Tab bar
    }
}
```

}

Any change on this from iOS 16 to 17? It used to work before the upgrade.

Comment: I don't know if it has changed. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77330632/20386264) might help you to find a solution.

Comment: TabView should always be on top, each tab should have its own Stack

Comment: Thank you. You mean its own NavigationStack? I agree.

Like the comment pointed out, a ZStack with a switch-case on the selectedTab might be a better approach.

Comment: Each tab gets its own NavigationStack