# TabView is showing toolbar, even though I have it marked hidden, setting page style causes clipping

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view, state

I have a `TabView` that contains a custom `PageView` which is merely a `ScrollView` and that `ScrollView` contains several `some View` objects. The entire thing is wrapped in a `NavigationStack`, and for every page, there is a new view added to my `TabView`.

```swift
 NavigationStack {
        TabView(selection: $selectedPageIndex) {
            ForEach(appConfig.pages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                let page = appConfig.pages[index]
                PageView(topPadding: $navBarHeight,
                         bottomPadding: $tabBarHeight,
                         page: page)
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                .tag(index)
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            VStack {
                navBar
                    .getHeight(height: $navBarHeight)
                
                Spacer()
                
                TabBar(selectedPageIndex: $selectedPageIndex)
                    .getHeight(height: $tabBarHeight)
            }
        }
```

I have this weird behavior, where if I change the `selectedPageIndex` a few times, the `.toolbar` reappears. This happens on the canvas, simulator, or real device. As pictured here.

[image: Toolbar is hidden, but it still reappears.]

The second problem I'm running into is that I need this `TabView` to be "Fullscreen" as I'm using it to host my pages, and in effect creating a custom `NavigationBar` and `TabBar` with it's own items. Whenever I attempt to add `.ignoresSafeArea()` along with `.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))` changing the `selectedPageIndex` "Sometimes" works, but mostly just doesn't do anything.

```swift
.ignoresSafeArea()
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.overlay {
```

Instead now, the underlying view, is clipped in an unexpected way, rather than extending the full height of the view. It's also present in the canvas, simulator, and real device.

[image: Notice that the view is not extending fully, to the bottom of the screen.]

Oddly, whenever I load it for the first time, everything renders as you'd expect, the bottom is not clipped. I can use drag gestures to swap the tab, or even select the new tab with the TabBar, however immediately, the view jumps up and starts clipping, as if the frame changed on it's own. In order to fix it, I must reset the view.

Comment: The answer to this question might help: [SwiftUI TabView adding strange blank space underneath view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77330632/20386264) In particular, see the description of an alternative approach in the last paragraph.

Comment: You can hide the tab bar using `UITabBar.appearance().alpha = 0`.

Comment: Have you tried setting `ignoresSafeArea()` on the PageView?

Comment: I've tried all of these things. I think there's some conflict between `NavigationStack` and the `TabView` which causes it. I managed to get it working in some capacity, but still a WIP. I'll repost here with a solution if I find one.

Comment: A TabView shouldn’t be inside the NavigationStack, each tab must be mutually exclusive. Give each tab their own NavigationStack