# .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) not working under iOS 17.4

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm experiencing an issue with hiding the tab bar in a SwiftUI TabView after updating both my simulator and physical device to iOS 17.4.

```swift
TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
    Group {
        View1()
            .tag(0)

        View2()
            .tag(1)
    }
    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
}
```

View1 is the default view and contains a scroll view. Initially, upon launching the app, everything works as expected, and the tab bar is correctly hidden. The problem arises when I switch to View2 (where the tab bar remains hidden as it should), but then upon returning to View1, the tab bar becomes visible again.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this behaviour?

I checked on previous iOS versions and it seems this only occurs on iOS 17.4.

Comment: Why are you using a `TabView`, if the tab bar is not visible? A `ZStack` would be an alternative approach.

Comment: I'm using a custom tab bar.

Comment: Sounds like all the more reason *not* to use a `TabView`. Just use a `ZStack` instead. See also the answer to [SwiftUI TabView adding strange blank space underneath view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77330632/20386264)

Comment: Same here, have you found out the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. At least not an elegant one. Wrapping TabView in NavigationStack seems to get rid of the issue, but in no way, shape or form is this a sustainable solution.

Comment: @TrinhTran I don't know how i didn't realize it earlier but with iOS 16 up we can set toolbar background to hidden: .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar). For my implementation (where I have no elements in native tab bar) this works just fine. Untill they fix this issue this would be the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what behavior you are looking for but you might want to put the modifier on the view. Not sure if this helps. You can place the NavigationStack and NavigationLink on this view to help navigation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Home")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
            
            Text("Settings")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                }
            View1()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("More", systemImage: "1.circle")
                }
            View2()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("More", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("View 1")
        }
    }
}
struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("View 2")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem.  Seems like Apple busted a bunch of things in iOS 17.4.  I was able to work around this by explicitly setting the visibility of the tab bar in various .onAppear/.onDisappear closures.  In particular, I defined

```
@State var visibility = Visibility.visible
```

and

```
.toolbar(visibility, for: .tabBar)
```

in one of my main views and then passed `visibility` to a `@Binding` in a bunch of other views, and then set

```
visibility = .visible
```

or

```
visibility = .hidden
```

in various places.

Seems to work (thankfully) on previous versions of iOS 17 and 16.